# Find a random integer which creates another integer, when using percentages

Tags: java, math

**Solved, for the precise solution for my problem, see my answer**

I am sorry about the confusing title, let me clarify my problem:

My Java program is supposed to ask a math question with percentages.

It should create a question in this format:

```
25% of 4616 = ?
```

The requirements are:

- the percentage is always dividable by 5 (no problem)
- the number (here 4616) has to be between 100 and 9999 (also not a problem)
- the number as well as the result has to be an integer (this is my problem)

Is there any fast method to find a random number which fulfills the last requirement?

The only solution I can think of is to find the percentage, then create a loop which will not stop until a random number is found which fulfills the requirement (in the example until `number % 4 == 0` is true)

But this loop could run thousands of times until a correct number is found.

Is there a better method for my problem?

**Edit:**
It seems that I didn't make clear what my problem is, I don't want double numbers as a result, only integer.

E.g.: If my percentage is 65%, then a possible question would be

> 65% of 7620 = ?

because the solution 4953 is also a whole number.

I want to find a random number between 100 and 9999 which is a whole number AND has a whole number as a result to the equation p * x = y.

Comment: @sbat this will not work, percentage is not the same as division. An example: 94*95 = 8930, but 8930*0,95 = 8483,5 (double, no integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `p` be the percentage (the numerator, i.e. 25%), `x` by the initial value and `y` be the resulting integer.

Since `p` is a percentage which is a multiple of 5 and from `0 to 100` then we can represent it as `p = 5a/100 = a/20` where `0 <= a <= 20`.

For `x` we have the constraint that `100 <= x <= 999`.

First pick an `a` that satisfies `0 <= a <= 20`.

Next we pick an `x`. Well, for `p * x = (a/20) * x` to be an integer result we just need 20 to divide `a * x`. Well, we know that `20 | (a * x)` ("20 divides a * x") if and only if

```
j = (a * x) / 20 (<- j is some integer)
<=> j = (a * x) / (2^2 * 5^1)
```

Since we have `a` we can replace it by its prime factorization:

```
j = (p1^e1 * p2^e2 * ... * pn^en) * x / (2^2 * 5^1)
```

Now realize that `a` is less than 20 so it's prime factorization is probably pretty simple and likely to "overlap" with the prime factorization. For example, if `a = 5` then the above equation simplifies to

```
j = x / 4
```

In which case it's easy to see how we can generate `x` that will produce an integer `j` (multiples of 4. Though you need `100 <= x <= 9999` too!). So "overlapping" (i.e. prime factors in the numerator which are the same as the denominator) are super beneficial. That's where the greatest common divisor comes into play. The `GCD(a, 20)` is the largest integer that divides both `a` and `20`. The prime factorization of the `GCD` is precisely the overlap. It also has the nice property that, once we "remove" the overlap, the resulting values:

```
j = b * x / c
```

Have the nice property that `b` and `c` are coprime. From that we know that `b * x / c` is an integer if and only if `c | x`.

So let `GCD(a, 20) = k`. Then by definition we have `a/k = b` and `20/k = c`, so `a/20 = b/c`. Therefore let `x = c * m` where `m` is an integer. Then we have:

```
100 <= m * c <= 9999
=> 100 / c <= m <= 9999 / c
```

So we can do a `floor(rand(100 / c, 9999 / c))` to produce your `m`.

To summarize:

```
a = rand(0, 20)
p = 5*a
c = 20 / GCD(a, 20)
m = floor(rand(100 / c, 9999 / c))
x = c * m
y = (p / 100) * x
```

Note that `a = 0` is actually an edge case and furthermore, `floor()` won't give you a completely uniform distribution. If you need these to be covered I can probably think about it and tweak the answer a bit. Also, the euclidean algorithm is trivial to implement, you can look it up. Heck, since `a < 20` you could probably just hardcode the function :)

**edit** I forgot to define `c` in my summary the first time through. Here's an example to produce the counter-example you had below:

```
a = 5
p = 25
c = 20 / GCD(5, 20) = 20 / 5 = 4
m = some integer in [25, 2500). In this case so we randomed 879
x = 3516
y = 879
```

Conveniently in this example we have `GCD(a, 20) = 5` so it turns out that `m = y`, but that's not always the case.

Comment: Thanks, the greatest common divisor was the missing piece i counld't think of! I will accept this answer, although the code was a little bit confusing and didn't function correctly with my problem. But the gcd did the trick, see my answer.

Comment: @Lotzki It was a bit convoluted, but it was just algebraic manipulating to get the formulas as simple as possible. (I wanted to show that you could use algebra + constraints and reach the answer). I forgot to post the definition of `c` in my summary and I also forgot to divide `p` by 100. I added that as well as an example to show you that the formulas should work. Looking at your answer, you have pretty much identical calculations as above (though you used different notation), but you had `y = floor(x * a / 20)`. Note that `a / 20 = 5a / 100 = p / 100` which is what I have now :)

Answer (score 1):

I would just select a percentage and work backwards from the answer to arrive at the question:

```
p * x = answer | 0 < p < 100, p = 5k, 100 <= x < 10000
```

So, pick your percentage:

```
p = (5 * rand(1, 9)) / 100.0;
```

Make sure your `100 <= answer / p < 10000`:

```
answer = rand(100, p * 9999);
```

Solve for the 'unknown':

```
x = p / y
```

Comment: This will not solve my problem, I tried to clarify my problem in my original question

Comment: @Lotzki Whoops, the percent calculation is indeed wrong. Will edit to fix it. That should be the only issue though (other than it being pseudocode)

Comment: Again, this is only the mathematical equation, this will not solve my problem. See my answer and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the divider is dependant on the `p` value. So, pick `p` first, then use it to calculate the divider to select the random number in the range:

```
For 5% it should be dividable by 20 (5/100 = 1/20)
For 10% it should be dividable by 10 (10/100 = 1/10)
For 15% it should be dividable by 20 (15/100 = 3/20)
For 20% it should be dividable by 5 (20/100 = 1/5)
For 25% it should be dividable by 4 (25/100 = 1/4)
For 30% it should be dividable by 10 (30/100 = 3/10)
...
```

You can calculate it by reducing the fraction `p/100` and picking the denominator

*below answer is not correct*

Looks like you'll have to pick numbers from the range of 100-9999 which are dividable by 20.

```
answer = x * p/100 = x * k/20 (since p is dividable by 5)
k = rand(1,494)
x = 100 + 20*k
p = 5*rand(1,20)
```

Comment: Yes, I have thought of that too, but this would not cover every possible solution.

Comment: @Lotzki can you think any example which is not covered?

Comment: You're right, you'll have to pick the divider based on the `p` value, updated my answer

Comment: This was very helpful, but the missing part was the greatest common divisor function as mentioned in the other answer

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to roliu I finally found a solution.
This is how my final solution looks like:

Create a random number between 1 and 20 (because percentage is dividable by 5):

```
a = rand(1,20)
```

Find greatest common divisor:

```
b = gcd(a,20)
```

Create a random number in the range divided by 20/gcd (see denis answer if you dont know why):

```
c = rand(floor(100/(20/b)),floor(9999/(20/b)))
```

Multiply the random number by 20/gcd to get a number in the range, our x:

```
x = floor(c * (20/b))
```

Multiply the number by the percentage to get the solution y:

```
y = floor(x * (a/20))
```

Converting the percentage to the correct value to be printed:

```
p = a * 5
```

Final equation:

```
p % of x = y
```